# Fill Na's in column with previous/next value +- 100

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df column that looks like this:

```
**Price**
1000
NaN
NaN
NaN
1500
NaN
```

I want to fill the NaN's with previous value plus add to it 100. So it would look like this:

```
**Price**
    1000
    1100
    1200
    1300
    1500
    1600
```

I've tried this:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].fillna(df['Price'].ffill()+100)
```

And it works if there is only one missing value in between price values. I would like to have something that works with multiple missing values in between values that are present, also in case the first value in column is NaN I would like it to be filled by the result of deducting 100 from the next value.
Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by groups generated by testing not missing values with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), multiple `100` and add to forward filling misisng values:

```
s = df.groupby(df['Price'].notna().cumsum()).cumcount().mul(100)
df['Price'] = df['Price'].ffill() + s

print (df)
    Price
0  1000.0
1  1100.0
2  1200.0
3  1300.0
4  1500.0
5  1600.0
```